# Google + Domain error when I try to post an activity

Tags: php, google-plus, google-api-php-client, google-plus-domains

I've been developing a feature for an extension in TYPO3 to post activities to a Google Plus domain profile.

I use the following code to instantiate the Google Client

```
    $googleClient = new Google_Client();
    $googleClient->setApplicationName("NAME");

    $googleClient->setClientId("123456789");
    $googleClient->setClientSecret("qwertyuiop");
    $googleClient->setRedirectUri("CALLBACK_URL");

    $googleClient->setScopes(array(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write',
    ));

    $googleClient->setRequestVisibleActions('http://schema.org/AddAction');
    $googleClient->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $googleClient->setAccessType('offline');
```

All values are like token are verified.

Then store the profiles obtaining the `refreshToken` to make the POST many times. Now the code of POST

```
    $googleClient->refreshToken($this->refreshToken);
    $googleClient->verifyIdToken();
    $plusdomains = new Google_Service_PlusDomains($googleClient);
    $post = new Google_Service_PlusDomains_Activity();
    $post['object']['originalContent'] = 'HELLO WORLD';

        try {
        $result = $plusdomains->activities->insert('me', $post);}
        catch (\Exception $e){
            var_dump($e);
        }
```

The line that is inside the try generates an error that is:

> Access to the Google+ Domains API is not allowed as the user has
>   consented to incompatible scopes. See:
>   https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/

I have searched for additional information about the error, which indicates that are the permissions or scopes, even in other questions of this same forum a few years ago. However I checked on https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/scopes and the ones I'm using are there. I would appreciate you guiding me in solving this problem.

Comment: Remove the scope `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile' `, then revoke app access from [here](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) and then try again.

Comment: @Morfinismo thank you!! I had not seen it. Now I have other error about 'Invalid Value', I am going to search about it.

Comment: I can see why you get the error too... you are not building the activity resource properly. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894829/google-activity-must-be-an-instance-of-google-activityobject/42916060#42916060)

Comment: @Morfinismo thanks again!! It works now! I am going to read more and play about media upload and visibility.